# How to take a string and return a list of all the words in a dictionary that differ from this word by exactly one letter?

Tags: python, search, dictionary

So right now I'm working with a very long dictionary of words from A-Z. With this dictionary I'm trying to create a function that takes a string as a parameter and returns all words within that dictionary that are one letter different at any point. Eg.

```
>>> oneLetterDiff('find')
    ['bind', 'kind', 'lind', 'mind', 'rind', 'wind', 'fend', 'fond', 'fund', 'fine', 'fink', 'finn', 'fins']
    >>> words=oneLetterDiff('hand')
    >>> print words
    ['band', 'land', 'rand', 'sand', 'wand', 'hard', 'hang', 'hank', 'hans']
    >>> oneLetterDiff('horse')
    ['morse', 'norse', 'worse', 'house', 'horde', 'horst']
    >>> oneLetterDiff('monkey')
    ['donkey']
    >>> oneLetterDiff('action')
    []
```

I've imported a separate function which is working perfectly at the moment I've called WordLookup. It looks like this:

```
def createDictionary():
    """
    Creates a global dict of all the words in the word file.
    Every word from the word list file because a key in the dict.
    Each word maps to the value None.  This is because all we care about
    is whether a given word is in the dict.

    """
    global wordList # Specifies that wordList will not go away at the end
                    # of this function call and that other functions may
                    # use it
    wordList = dict()
    wordFile = open('WordList.txt')
    for word in wordFile:
        word = word.strip() # remove leading or trailing spaces
        # map the word to an arbitrary value that doesn't take much
        # space; we'll just be asking "in" questions of the dict
        wordList[word] = None 
    wordFile.close()


def lookup(word):
    global wordList # states that the function is using this global variable
    return word in wordList
```

Following this code I have the actual oneLetterDiff function:

```
def oneLetterDiff(myString):
        theAlphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
        for i in myString:
            for j in theAlphabet:
                #Maybe try to see if the letters can be changed in this fashion?
```

Is anyone able to help me understand this a bit better? I've really been struggling to figure out a proper solution and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. There is a good python [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/) that implements the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) metric. I think you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a utility function called `close_enough`.  It takes two words and returns `True` if the words have the same length and differ by one and only one letter:

```
def close_enough(word1, word2):
    return len(word1) == len(word2) and 1 == sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(word1, word2))
```

Next, we need a function to search through the word list, called `wordlist`, and select the words that are `close_enough` (differ by one letter).  Here is a function to do that.  It takes two arguments: the word to compare against, called `myword` and the `wordlist`:

```
def one_letter_diff(myword, wordlist)
    return [word for word in wordlist if close_enough(word, myword)]
```

If you prefer, we could make `wordlist` a global:

```
def one_letter_diff2(myword):
    # Uses global wordlist
    return [word for word in wordlist if close_enough(word, myword)]
```

Generally, though, program logic is easier to understand if globals are avoided.

#### Examples

Here is `close_enough` in action finding which words differ by one letter and which don't:

```
In [22]: close_enough('hand', 'land')
Out[22]: True

In [23]: close_enough('hand', 'lend')
Out[23]: False
```

Here is `one_letter_diff` in action looking for words in `wordlist` that differ by one letter from `hand`:

```
In [26]: one_letter_diff('hand', ['land', 'melt', 'cat', 'hane'])
Out[26]: ['land', 'hane']
```

#### How it works

Let's look first at `close_enough`.  It returns True if two conditions are satisfied.  The first is that the words have the same length:

```
len(word1) == len(word2)
```

The second is that they differ by only one letter:

```
1 == sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(word1, word2))
```

Let's break that down into parts. This returns True for every letter that differs:

```
[x!=y for x,y in zip(word1, word2)]
```

For example:

```
In [37]: [x!=y for x,y in zip('hand', 'land')]
Out[37]: [True, False, False, False]
```

`sum` is used to count the number of letters that differ.

```
In [38]: sum(x!=y for x,y in zip('hand', 'land'))
Out[38]: 1
```

If that sum is one, then the condition is satisfied.

The command in `one_letter_diff` is a _list comprehension`:

```
[word for word in wordlist if close_enough(word, myword)]
```

It goes through each word in `wordlist` and includes it in the final list *only if* `close_enough` returns True.